# Vertical-align a div relative to parent div

Tags: css, html

I have divs (child) in a div (parent). The height from the parent is 144 to 318 (min-height and max-height). It depends on the size of the window.

I want every child in the parent to be vertically aligned. I tried it with line-height but since I don't have a fixed height, I can't find an answer.

Any suggestions how to do it?

HTML File:

```
<div id="mainDivPad">
    <div id="ipadPad">
        BILD
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS File:

```
#mainDivPad{
position: relative;
width:100%;
height:100%;
min-height:144px;
max-height:318px;
background-color:#f9e2ef;
}
#ipadPad{
float: right;
margin-right: 7%;
}
```

edit:

The child has to "move" and get smaller oder taller when the window size is changed. (I know that the smaller and taller thing is another topic and should not be the problem here)

Answer (score 0):

Use Line height for vertical alignment

line-height:inherit or line-height:parent dive hieght

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by position it absolute:

```
#ipadPad {
    margin-right: 7%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
}
```

The `margin-top` has to be the half height of the element `#ipadPad`.

[Live Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KittMedia/5Dtub/)

Comment: I have no fixed values, that's the problem.

Comment: Then calculate them with jQuery: `$('#ipadPad').css({ 'margin-top': -$('#ipadPad').height() / 2 });`. See http://jsfiddle.net/KittMedia/5Dtub/1/

Comment: Okay. I added more information at the end of my question. The position has to change when I change the size of the window.